# Нужны ли запятые, если дата не является уточнением?

Tags: запятые

Нужны ли запятые в таком предложении:
«Субботу 27 января мы провели на катке».

Answer (score 1):

1. Корректно выглядит такая запись: ***Субботу 27 января** мы провели на катке.*

Отношения между обстоятельствами **неоднородные,** запятой нет. Сообщается полная информация (дата и день недели).

2. **Уточнение** возможно: Субботу, **27 января**, мы провели на катке.

Такая запись делается в том случае,  когда дата указывается как **дополнительная** информация.

Comment: … _**или на следующей**_  ❓ === Не согласуется с **прошедшим** временем глагола «провели».

Comment: Спасибо, я исправила.